# javascript selenium webdriver is not full size

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, electron

I have code like this

```
const mainScreen = electron.screen.getPrimaryDisplay();
const windowHeight = mainScreen.size.height;
const windowWidth = mainScreen.size.width;

driver.manage().window().setRect({width: windowWidth, height: windowHeight, x: 0, y: 0});
driver.get('http://www.google.com');
```

and I've got 2 issues with that:

- It resize chrome window after google.com is loaded instead when window pops up.
- It's actually too high (because of windows bottom bar) and it's not broad enough - it leave space at the left and right:

[image: ALT]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The screen resolution is not necessarily equal to the browser when it is in full screen. If you set the browser size base on the computer screen you will see gaps like those. You can see it by using Selenium `maximize()` function to get full screen and then `getRect()`, you will see it is different from `windowWidth` and `windowHeight`

Use Selenium `maximize()` function to set the browser size

```
driver.manage().window().maximize()
```

Comment: It works but it still doesn't miximize window instantly after window open but after some time like 1sec maybe.

Comment: Also can I maximize only height and set custom width?

Comment: @BT101 The delay is common, I have it as well.

Comment: @BT101 You can use `getRect()` after maximizing to get the "real" dimensions and then use  `setRect()` based on this data.

Comment: Big thanks, do you know if I can wait untill user navigate to specific url?

Comment: @BT101 I'm not sure I understand the question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189393/discussion-between-bt101-and-guy).